# ResponseEntity returning an Optional

Tags: java, controller, option-type

I've been told I should refactor the return type of this method in my controller so it doesnt return a generic <?> :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return myService.getById(id).map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
    }
```

`myService.getById`
returns an `Optional<DestinyDTO>`, im confused about wether it is correct to return a `ResponseEntity<Optional<DestinyDTO>>` or not. If so, how can i replace the `<?>` return Type to match the actual return type in my service method getById.

Hopefully i explained myself. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `ResponseEntity<DestinyDTO>`.

Answer (score 1):

your entity's response should be more explicit.

If your response entity is something like this `ResponseEntity<?>`, you are declaring that you can return any type of data.

but if you return something like this `ResponseEntity<User>` you are declaring that your response has an explicit data, this helps a lot because you specify that your entity will respond to anyone who consumes your API, and if you use Swagger it will be documented explicitly and not a simple ?.

Comment: I think you said "like this `ResponseEntity<?>` you can return **any** type of data" you may have meant "like this `ResponseEntity<?>` you can return any `ResponseEntity` type of data" -- if so, can you [edit] your answer to clarify?  Thanks.